# IIS Express with portnumbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have a ASP.Net MVC project in maintenance. Apparantely the IISExpress is adding portnumbers to localhost which is fine. except when the relative style sheet link does not contain the portnumbers?

How come the portnumbers are not added automaticaly? Seems pretty logical to me that when Visual Studio 2013 starts up it sends the browser to localhost with portnumber but when building the relative style sheet links it does not?

Guy

In view file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./metrouicss.css" />
```

After running in IISexpress:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost//Templates/Design 2/metrouicss.css" />
```

Since IISexpress is running on port 42532 I would rather see it rendered like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:42532//Templates/Design 2/metrouicss.css" />
```

Comment: Please, show some code so that we can understand the exact problem. If not there are many chances that your question get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry try this (I missed the rest of the path):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Templates/Design 2/metrouicss.css" />
```

Or

If you are using MVC 5 you can use the BundleConfig class:

```
Public Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
                bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Templates/css").Include(
                    "~/Templates/Design 2/metrouicss.css"))
End Sub
```

And in view use the following in the  tags:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Templates/css")
```